# Excel COUNTIFS and time range

Tags: excel

Trying to use COUNTIFS formula to see if our facility was open for business.

I need column D to show "Open" if Column B value is between 8:00 AM and 4:30 PM and it Column C has to be a weekday.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see. Paste this in cell D. Make sure the columns are correct. This formula is not looking at column C. It takes the week day from column A.

**Updated** formula

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)>1,IF(WEEKDAY(A2)<7,IF(B2>=TIMEVALUE("8:30:00"),IF(B2<=TIMEVALUE("16:30:00"),"Open","Closed"),"Closed"),"Closed"),"Closed")
```

Comment: This is working but I am getting #NAME? error for columns that have a weekday and the time is after 4:30PM. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Shoot... Put double quotes around the first `Closed`. Forgot that. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Cheers